# How to export and using sequelize models nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodes, sequelize-cli

This is my node model using sequelize:

`

```
"use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      User.hasMany(sequelize.models.Article, {
        foreignKey: "posts",
      });
    }
  }
  User.init(
    {
      firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
      lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
      age: DataTypes.STRING,
      email: DataTypes.STRING,
      password: DataTypes.STRING,
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "User",
    }
  );
  return User;
};
```

but this error, but I'm not able to use the module in other files, I want to use it in the Service, and I'm imposing it like this:
`

```
`const user = require("../models/user");

module.exports = {
  async listUsers(req, res) {
    const users = user.findAll();
    await console.log(user);
    res.send("okok");
    // const users = await User;
    // res.send(users);
  },
}`
```

`

this error says:  TypeError: user.findAll is not a function``

Prescso usar o model em outros arquivos, acredito que estou importando incorretamene por ser uma função

Answer (score 0):

You've made a typo when calling the function.

It's not

```
user.findAll();
```

but

```
User.findAll();
```

That's how you have defined the model, also make sure the import has the right uppercase.